# Gradient direction

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I learned at the math classes that the gradient at a point is perpendicular to the surface but our electromagnetism teacher taught us that the gradient is tangent to the graph and it points in the direction of the steepest ascent. Which is the right way to interpret it? Is it perpendicular or tangent?

Comment: Extra: the gradient lives in the cotangent space of a manifold.

Answer (score 0):

It's tangent to the graph and perpendicular to the level curve.  Think of a sphere, you're a standing on the equator heading to the north pole.  Then the direction is tangent to the sphere and perpendicular to the equator.

Comment: That is also the way I see it, but my math teacher says it is a normal vector to the surface at any point.

Comment: Either you misunderstood him or he's wrong.